# java.nio.file.Files.exists() behavior on AIX

Tags: java, nio, aix

I've a download method that tests if a file exists before delivering it to the user.

```
if( Files.exists(path) ) {
...
}
```

The test is failing for all files, I've checked file's permissions on the server and they're set with `755`. If I change them to `775` the test works as expected and I'm able to download the files.
Maybe I'm using the `exists()` method in the wrong way, but I was expecting it to test, at the most, read permissions. Is this how the method is supposed to behave or is this a bug?

**EDIT #1**

The user that's executing the application server is different from the user generating the files, but they both belong to the same group.

The following test is working as expected on one of the files' parent directories:

```
if( Files.isreadable(parentDirectory) ) {

...

}
```

I've double checked the permissions on this folder, sub-folders and files and they're all set to `755`.

Comment: What happens if you use `Files.isReadable(path)` instead?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, haven't tried yet for these files, but I'm doing that test for a parent directory with the same permissions and works as expected. I know how to workaround the problem, I'm just curious with the odd behavior.

Comment: Well, if it works for a parent directory, you should provide more details, such as the permissions of the directory where the files that don't work reside, vs. the permissions of the parent directory. Also, check if the directory is a mount point or part of the same filesystem.

Comment: Also, does it work if you change to 775 and then again to 755 (on the same file)?

Comment: What do you mean _download?_ Maybe your 'path' variable contains an URL that points to a remote computer?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, the file is served via HTTP, but the files being served are located in a directory on the same machine where the server is running.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I'll have to check that next morning, I'm no longer at work. It is important to mention that the user running the server is different from the user owning the files, although both belong to the same group. I've edited the permissions on the parent directory recursively.

Comment: Why are you testing this at all? Just try to open the file. You have to do that anyway, and opening the file has to test for existence anyway, and throw `FileNotFoundException` if it isn't found. You're just doubling the work.

Comment: @EJP, just to show more informative messages. Anyway, that's not the real issue, I'm intrigued about the method's behavior.